# Variable In Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add variable in an array but failed to do so please help me out.

Below is Original code which works fine

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

and it output this

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

But I want to add variable in array so array gets value from the variable but it's not working

What I am trying

```
$a = '"green", "red", "blue"';
$b = '"green", "yellow", "red"';
$array1 = array("a" => $a);
$array2 = array("b" => $b );  
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

I want it to output like this

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

What I am getting

```
Array ( )
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post expected output.

Comment: `$w` is undefined in this example &Of course the first preview is correct, as it's straight from the manual. What is your expected results? and what are you getting?

Comment: Added my expected output

Comment: @DarylGill sorry that's a typo

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have tried is assigning the string `'"green", "red", "blue"'` to the array element `"a"` when what you appear to want is to split the string like so that `"green red blue"` becomes `array("green","red","blue")`

```
$a = "green red blue";
$array1 = split(" ",$a);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string '"green", "red", "blue"' not an array. In your snippet

> $a = '"green", "red", "blue"';
>   $b = '"green", "yellow", "red"';
>   $array1 = array("a" => $a);
>   $array2 = array("b" => $w );
>   $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
>   print_r($result);

PHP will understand `$a` and `$b` as strings. If you meant to pass an array to `$a` and `$b` you will need to change it to

```
$a = array("green", "red", "blue");
$b = array("green", "yellow", "red");
```

Then make your intersection. If you use an `var_dump($a)` you will see that `$a` is storing an String variable.